# Should i setup 1 EC2 for multiple IIS websites or multiple EC2 with fewer IIS on AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, iis

I have several customers and i am serving different versions of my .net web application, using different MS SQL databases to all of my customers. I'm moving to AWS and i need help from experienced people.

On Azure i create a sepereate resource group, sql server, app plan, app service for all my clients.
On my local server, i have multiple clients on one windows server and one sql server with multiple databases.

So my question is again, should i create one EC2 instance and use this instance to serve all my clients or is there a better way on AWS?

Comment: There isn't a best unless your requirements on "security, load handling, cost and etc" are super clear, but they aren't now. So this isn't a question that can be answered at this moment.

Comment: There is no definite answer. If you have multiple websites, you can host them in IIS on the same EC2 Windows Server instance. IIS differentiates between websites by using bindings, which are a combination of protocol type, IP address, port, and hostname. To avoid IP and port conflicts, you need to add a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You've really got one of two options conceptually speaking. You either;

1. Use shared resources and deal with the config magic under the hood. i.e. 1x EC2, 1x RDS for example.
2. Use separate resources and segment things at a lower level (and hardware level) i.e. 2x EC2, 2x RDS for example.

Then you have the additional security considerations with both options and additional management to get this setup.

There are many ways to skin this cat. Really depends on what you want to achieve and why etc.